# Glmer: Factor response variables versus numeric response variables

Tags: logistic, lme4-nlme

Using a linear mixed effects model, I am investigating the drivers of forest loss in parks. The drivers of forest loss are (dist_city, dist_road, altitude, slope, altitude and rainfall) and my response variable is forest loss (binary, 1 = forest loss and 0 = no forest loss). Since I have multiple points of forest loss in 224 parks, I have included the name of the parks as a random effect.

Therefore my model is:

```
glmer(loss~dist_city+dist_road+rainfall+altitude+slope+(1|name), data=Fail, family=binomial)
```

Running the glmer with these variables as factors or numeric variables produces very different outputs, which I think should not happen? As my response variable (forest loss) can only be a 0 or 1. I understand that this should be a factor. However, I am not sure what the predictor variables should be. If they are factors, the glmer output indicates that I do not have enough memory size to allocate. If the predictor variables are numeric, the glmer output gives me a warning message:

```
> Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00789456 (tol = 0.001, component 1)
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
 - Rescale variables?;Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
 - Rescale variables?
```

Why does the R output differ and what is the correct way forward?

Comment: Are there more than one entries (rows) for each (or many) parks? If there is only one entry for each park, the term (1|name) should not be put.

Comment: There are multiple entries for each park because there are multiple points generated in each park. Each point encompasses a forest loss, rainfall, slope, altitude, distance from road and distance from slope value.

Comment: The warning suggest you to scale the variables. Why not try with scaled predictor variables? Also you mention "I have included the name of the parks as a fixed effect". But this should be 'random' effect and not fixed effect.

Comment: Thank you - I have edited my question. As suggested, I rescaled two predictor variables (distance to road and distance to city) as these were is meters, whereas slope and altitude are in square kilometers. Rainfall is in mm and now is the only value in the 1000s. However, after running the model I still received the same warning....

Comment: Try: loss~scale(dist_city)+ scale(dist_road)+ scale(rainfall)+ scale(altitude)+ scale(slope) + (1|name) . Meters or kilometers or mm do not matter in this method.

Comment: @mso I cannot thank you enough!! I have been struggling with this analysis for days and, after trying your last recommendation, I have a working model! Thank you!!

Comment: I find it strange how R produces variable responses based on a variable's category. If all variables were left default, R would make all variables a factor except for rainfall, altitude and loss. This would produce a warning: fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 99 columns/coefficients. If all variables were factors except for the response variable, R would produce a warning: Error: cannot allocate vector of size 5.1 Gb. I have never realized the importance of checking what R has categorized variables as and I wonder if anyone has the time to explain to me these occurrences?

Comment: You must always check the nature of variables by using "str(mydataframe)" command (str for structure). If needed you can convert variables by as.numeric() or as.factor() or as.ordered() functions. At time of making a dataframe, R assumes the variable to be numeric if all entries are numeric, else it makes it a factor variable. For more queries on R programming, you should post at stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling my comments:If there is only one entry for each park, the term (1|name) should not be put.

The warning suggest you to scale the variables. Why not try with scaled predictor variables?

Also you mention "I have included the name of the parks as a fixed effect". But this should be 'random' effect and not fixed effect.

Instead of converting the units of different variables, one can convert them to SD units with simple R command 'scale' as follows:

```
loss~scale(dist_city)+ scale(dist_road)+ scale(rainfall)+ scale(altitude)+ scale(slope) + (1|name)
```

Meters or kilometers or mm do not matter in this method.